# Outllook ask for Office 365/ Microsoft Logins rather than Exchange Logins

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, webmail

I have Exchange on premise and Office 2019 installed in PCs. In Outlook 2019, when someone open outlook, after some second, they always ask for Login to Microsoft website. If I close this, it's not works any more. I checked Server is up and fully working. I removed user profile from Laptop and added again, but still happens same. Furthermore, I changed Trust centre setting, but still they ask. Its happen in multiple PCs. If anyone have any clue about that, Please let me know. I added screenshot also. I tried all solution from MS website, but not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2anU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open the registry setting on Outlook client PC.
please add the following registry key to this location
HKEY_CURRENT_USER:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
DWORD: ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint Value = 1

If AutoDiscover doesn't exist, Please add a key by right click on outlook (HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook) and add a Key with the Name "AutoDiscover". Once you add that Key, click to add Dword (32Bit ) value. Click modify and add name ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint and add Value 1.

Now they will not ask for passwords again. If it still happens, Please restart your PC. I hope its work for you